# change the format of a cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using below vba code to copy a cell value from one sheet to another. The value will always be a number. I have formatted both source and target cells as a number. But whenever vba runs, I am getting message `" Number stored as text"` even though there is no change in cell format.
How can I resolve this?
VBA Code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set mw = Workbooks("StockScreen.xlsm").Sheets("MW")
    Set ws = Workbooks("StockScreen.xlsm").Sheets("TimeStampWork")
     If Value <> mw.Range("A2").Value Then
        Range("A2,E2").Copy
        ws.Range("B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Dim Max
        Dim Min
       Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("b:b"))
       Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Range("b:b"))


    Sheets("TimeStampWork").Range("F2") = Max
    Sheets("TimeStampWork").Range("G2") = Min
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If all you want to do is copy values, why use copy-paste at all? Just assign the `.Value` of the source range to the `.Value` of the target range.

Comment: @JohnColeman     Thanks for the suggestions. I changed my code accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be instead of

```
Range("A2,E2").Copy
ws.Range("B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

try

```
Range("A2,E2").Copy
With ws.Range("B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
End With
```

Comment: giving me paste special out of range error on .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False

Comment: Try : `ws.Range("B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = 
Range("A2,E2").Value`

Comment: @acr - Make sure `TimeStampWork` is a legit sheet name.

Comment: @Mrig:         I still getting the error and TimeStampWork is a valid sheet name.  I will try to verify it. Between its working when assigning the values as mentioned by Xire and  John

Comment: When I update it manually its working fine. But the cell values are getting updated using RTD function. Currently, RTD server is not available. I need to verify if its work with RTD function as well.